# TDD: When testing a ReST API Controller is it prudent to test all actions (create, update, get, delete, etc) all in a single test-file?

Tags: rest, unit-testing, testing, tdd, integration-testing

This is clearly a practical question. Internet wisdom suggests logically organizing tests for maintainability. When it comes to ReST API Controllers one could include all integration-tests for all actions of the controller in a single file.

Assuming we have 4 CRUD actions per controller with an average of 6 tests per action we are bound to end up with at least 24 tests in one file. In industrial-grade web-servers I suspect that this number would baloon way further upwards.

The thing is that these actions even though they are part of one class (controller) they are complex and orthocanonical (different resources/artifacts/mockups needed to test each group etc).

I'm having a hard time coming to terms that all these tests should be placed in one file given the fact that they are testing almost entirely different things and can be placed in 4 separate files. Isn't this more aligned with the spirit of TDD afterall?

Is my intuition misplaced?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is stopping you from organizing your tests in any way that makes sense for your project.

Internet wisdom has nothing to do with this, do what works for you. You want one test file per crud method? Then do that.

Where your tests live is far less important than what you actually test and how.

Just one note of caution, I have seen people spend a long time and test completely the wrong things.

Let's instantiate controllers to call methods from them ( don't, this is a sign of really bad SOC ), let's mock who knows what.

You will achieve a much better result if you unit test what should be unit tested and that is functional stuff, classes and methods that do stuff. For an API this will mean business rules, data transformations, model transformations, that kind of stuff.

For the rest, I'd stick with integrations tests, call your endpoints like a normal user would and this means mostly integration testing. Use something like Postman to organize collections of tests.

You'll have a lot less to mock, your tests won't be affected much if you change your implementation details, you'll be able to do measurements on your endpoints and you'll actually test the real thing, going all the way to your storage and back which no amount of mocking will give you.